# ColdFusion9: Can't connect to PayPal Sandbox (classic NVP)

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, coldfusion-9

Server: Windows Server 2012
Cold Fusion: 9,0,1,274733
Update-Level: hf901-00011.jar
Running on java version: 1.7.0_79
Java home points to the right path.

All certificates (for live and sandbox) are imported into the keystore of this JDK 1.7.0_79. I've tested it and renaming the cacerts file results in an error when connecting to the live API.

Testing the cacerts file using the keytool shows that the apropriate certificates are properly imported.

A little order app provides payment using PayPal.

First step is a connection to PayPal using the method "setExpressCheckout".
The connection to the live API using NVP at URL https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp works and delivers the token URL-string.
The connection to the sandbox API using NVP at URL https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp fails with the error response:

```
I/O Exception: peer not authenticated
Connection Failure
Unable to determine MIME type of file.
Connection Failure. Status code unavailable.
```

Calling the URL https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp from the server works.

**Test 1**

- imported the sandbox certificate for api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com
- restart CF service
- connection test failed with the same error

**Test 2**

- renamed the cacerts file to cacerts.bak
- copied the cacerts file from jre1.8.0_31\lib\security to the 1.7.0_79\lib\security
- there is no specific PayPal cert in the cacerts file
- restart the CF service
- connection to live API works
- connection to sandbox api fails with the same error

The weird thing is that the connection to the live api works without importing the specific certificate into the keystore when using the 1.8xx cacerts file.

I can't figure out why the connection to the sandbox fails. Maybe I can get new hints here?
If there are more informations needed please let me know. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have gotten notices from PayPal that they are going to disable TLS 1.1 and older ciphers (on 9/1/2017 I think).  Perhaps the sandbox has already disabled the older ciphers and the JRE that you are using is failing because it isn't using TLS 1.2.  This post may have better info: https://superuser.com/questions/747377/enable-tls-1-1-and-1-2-for-clients-on-java-7

Comment: @Scott thank u. I am now taking a look into the outbound session using -Djavax.net.debug=all in the JVM startup arguments. Maybe your answer leads me in a better direction.

Comment: Also note that the NVP/SOAP integration method of Paypal Express Checkout is deprecated as of January 1, 2017, which might be why the sandbox doesn't work anymore (I'm using TLS 1.2 and still can't connect)

Comment: After I've updated to JDK1.8.0_144 the connection works fine. Even without importing a certificate into the keystore.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved!

Scott Jibben (see his comment above) mentioned that the PayPal sandbox may already decline TLS1 connections in order to the upcoming change to do so in the PayPal live API.
This is absolutely right. But while in CF11 this isn't a problem because CF11 and its JRE are already using TLSv1.2, CF8-10 are using the default protocol of their JRE.
If not, one can force CF to use TLSv1.2 with the JVM argument

```
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

**Short:**

CF8-10 are using TLSv1 while running with JDK1.70_79 and below no matter what the JVM startup argument -Dhttps.protocols was set to.
This is because the default protocol of these Java versions is TLSv1 and CF8-10 are simply ignoring the JVM startup argument -Dhttps.protocols and always use the JDK's default protocol.
This has changed with CF11 therefore it works fine with it.

Read detailed informations in a post from Wil Genovese at:
https://www.trunkful.com/index.cfm/2014/12/8/Preventing-SSLv3-Fallback-in-ColdFusion

**What I did**

I've installed the JDK1.8.0_144 and set up Cold Fusion 9 to use this one. Since then the connection to the PayPal sandbox API at api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com works pretty well.

Hope this may help others with this old and by now a little odd CF9.